# Getting the number of values not in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to have a function count the number of values that are not present in a list. [image: spreadsheet]

I've tried using both =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(MATCH(J2:J4,H2:H10,0))) and =SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(H2:H10,J2:J4)=0)) but both just display zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the references:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(MATCH(H2:H10,J2:J4,0)))
```

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(J2:J4,H2:H10)=0))
```

Comment: had to add -COUNTIF('Detail Data'!J2:J501,"") to the end of the formula to deal with blanks, but it worked great!